# Finding the path between to points which minimizes cost function subject to constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I have a question regarding calculus of variations.
Given a cost function in configuration space how can I find the path between two points which minimizes it subject to constraints?
I am aware that one can obtain euler-lagrange equations, but that is not quite what I am looking for. I want to fix two points in configuration space and find the path which connects these points and minimizes the cost function.

Comment: Any example problem?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Well, take for example the problem of a point particle in a gravitational potential near the earth: $L=p^2/2m-mgx$. The Euler-Lagrange equations are simple and they give you a differential equation to solve which gives one the path subject to initial conditions. But what I am looking for is different. I want to know the path minimizing the action given two fixed points. Also, I mentioned that I want to subject the whole problem to a constraint. For that one could for example take two point particles in a potential and the distance between the two should remain constant.